# After subscribing to Changes.watch in google drive api, what is the response wait time until one gets the notification?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have subscribed to Google drive api's Changes.watch on a particular resource. The notification it sends back are not immediate after any changes in that particular resource.
Is there any time interval after which it triggers a notification?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, with proper setup, the Drive API will inform your application as soon as any watched resource changes.

Note that `Changes: watch` method is used to subscribe for updates to the change log; however, as discussed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push), there are actually three things that you need to do to use push notifications. You may want to check these:

> - Register the domain of your receiving URL.
>
>   For example, if you plan to use `https://example.com/notifications` as your receiving URL, you need to register `https://example.com`.
> - Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
>
>   This is an HTTPS server that handles the API notification messages that are triggered when a resource changes.
> - Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.
>
>   A channel specifies routing information for notification messages. As part of the channel setup, you identify the specific URL where you want to receive notifications. Whenever a channel's resource changes, the Drive API sends a notification message as a `POST` request to that URL.